# getting google's openid configuration Discovery document yields to cors errors

Tags: ajax, angularjs, openid, google-authentication, google-openid

I am trying to access the google discovery document through angular $http service, but I receive cors errors. https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

here is the error:

```
MLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1485' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I know it has to do with CORS, and I wanted to get the authorization endpoint in my angular service from that document after loading it. If I don't load the document and directly hardcode the authorization_endpoint (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth) everything is working, but I wanted to create a service that could be configured from the discovery endpoint.

**My Question is :**

*Does anyone succeeded in loading the google openId discovery document from ajax requests ? (from the angular $http service ?)*

regards

Comment: Did you try with jsonp instead of json

Comment: I tried the following : $http({
                    url: 'https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration?callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
                    method: "JSONP",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'
                    } , but received this error : (Refused to execute script from 'https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration?callback=angular.callbacks._0' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled)

Comment: @CedricDumont were you able to find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue here.